# Loading javascript global variables in angular 4 typescript source

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to include "parameters.js" file into my angular 4 project.

You can see below my "parameter.js" file content :

```
window.myKey = "http://webserviceUrl/"
```

I want to include this file in my project and get "myKey" value in a typescript file before loading web service datas.
My "parameters.js" file as a specific structure and do not be changed (no json :'( ).

Is anyone as loading js into typescript with angular 4 ? How can i do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you not simply include that file in index.html?

Comment: Maybe... but how can i use my global variable in typescript. When i do :

console.log('This my value'+myKey);

Angular display an error because this variable is not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to David explainations, i have added my parameters script in my angular conf ".angular-cli.json" like this :

```
"scripts": [
    "../directory/parameters.js"
],
```

I can read the value in typescript with the code :

```
declare let myKey: string;
```

Thank you David for you great response ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Include the script in index.html

```
<script src="/assets/parameters.js" />
```

And declare the variable in the component where you need to access it

```
declare let myKey: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Import js locally to ts file like this : import '../../../scripts/custom.js';

then declare method name in custom.js that you want to use like this 
declare var fAlert;
(declarations statements are usually put just after the import statements)
then in a place like ngOnInit directly use this method

fAlert();